# How to use textfield to enter numbers into a array (swift3)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3, uitextfield, reset

I have  a textfield that I would like the user to be able to enter numbers for a array in. Ideally the button would save the number, then clear the textfield for another number to be enter. This would be a process that would just go in a loop. So its just save the number, clear the number, repeat infinitely.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var enterText: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func submitText(_ sender: Any) {
}}
```

Comment: That's not a question, it's a development goal. What part do you need help with? Do you know hwo to get the value when the user taps your button? Ad it to your array? Clear the text? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets define and array.

```
 var arrayOfInt = [Int]()
```

Suppose you have button action method and **textField** Object (could be IB outlet) to which user enters number.

```
 @IBAction func submitText(_ sender: Any) {
      if let text = textField.text {

            if let number = Int(text){

            arrayOfInt.append(number)

            }else {

             print("Please enter number")

           }

       }
 }
```